# C# IEnumerable<XElement> - How to Xpath Filter on "root"?

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml

In C#, I have an IEnumerable of XElements. All of the XElements have the same name, but different types. I would like to perform an "xpath filter" on the "root" element of each XElement.

Sample XML:

```
<xml>
    <Location>
        <Type>Airport</Type>
        <Buildings></Buildings>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <Type>Mine</Type>
        <Buildings></Buildings>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <Type>Airport</Type>
        <Buildings></Buildings>
    </Location>
</xml>
```

Sample C#:

```
var elements = xml.Elements("Location");
```

What I need is to get all the Buildings where the Location/Type is "Airport". What I would **like** to do is something like:

```
elements.SelectMany(el => el.XPathSelectElements(".[Type = 'Airport']/Buildings/Building"));
```

However, I cannot figure out the xpath syntax for filtering at the "root" of the XElement (the ".[Type" part).

What I **can** do is:

1. Add the elements to a made-up root element, and then apply my xpath filter (because Location would no longer be at the "root").
2. Filter the Locations using Linq eg: `elements.Where(loc => loc.Element("Type").Value == "Airport")`

But I would like to learn if there is an xpath way.
Can anyone point me in the right direction for the xpath syntax?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
The above XML is an extremely dumbed-down sample. The *actual* XML is tens of thousands of lines long, relatively unpredictable (a change in the source object can change thousands of lines of XML), and its schema is not fully known (on my end). Some of the structures repeat and/or nest. Therefore, using "//" is unlikely sufficient. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Are you missing `</Location>` or locations are nested?

Comment: In not at my PC but in your *'I'd like to do'* try swapping `Type = 'Airport'` for `Type/text() = 'Airport'`. If it's right let me know, and I'll offer it as an answer.

Comment: @Fabio you are right, I am missing the </Location> closing tag, they should not be nested.

Comment: @Richardissimo: ".[Type/text() = 'Airport']" results in *has an invalid token*; "./[Type/text() = 'Airport']" and "[Type/text() = 'Airport']" result in *expression must evaluate to a node-set"; "./Type/text() = 'Airport'" results in *unexpected type System.Boolean* (which is closer!). Any idea where I messed up the syntax?

Comment: @emery.noel, if you need to handle big volume of data, namespaces and more complex structure than posted here, please edit your question and mention these details.

Comment: Who votes to close a question before it's answered?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't seem like what I want is possible. So instead, I went with creating a "fake root" element, added my XElement collection, and used an xpath:

```
var airportBlgs = new XElement("root", locations)
    .XPathSelectElements( "./Location[Type='Airport']/Building" );
```

The fake root means I don't have to use "//", which is too broad. It's too bad this can't be done using just xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var buildings = xml.XPathSelectElements("//xml/Location[Type=\"Airport\"]/Buildings");
```

Example:

```
string xmlString =
                @"<xml>
                    <Location>
                        <Type>Airport</Type>
                        <Buildings>First airport buildings</Buildings>
                    </Location>
                        <Type>Mine</Type>
                        <Buildings>Mine buildings</Buildings>
                    <Location>
                        <Type>Airport</Type>
                        <Buildings>Second airport buildings</Buildings>
                    </Location>
                </xml>";

XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var buildings = 
xml.XPathSelectElements("//xml/Location[Type=\"Airport\"]/Buildings");

foreach (var b in buildings)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(b.Value);
    }
```

Result:

```
 First airport buildings
 Second airport buildings
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have only the collection of XElements, not the entire document. Loading the elements into a root XElement will work, which I think might actually be better than an XDocument. In addition, I'm dealing with multiple sets of nested/duplicated elements, so the "//" might or might not work, depending on the (unknown) XML that will return.